# What is this view called in iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, user-interface

I am trying to implement a view like the one in this picture:

[image]

I would like to create a view with black background with a few buttons like "Cancel Draft," "Save Draft," and "Delete Draft" to appear on my screen when a user clicks a button.

I am not sure how to describe what this view is called and how to implement it. I like how it is black and it only covers the screen partially. It doesn't take up the whole screen.

Can someone please tell me what is this control/view called so I can summon it in my app and create some buttons?

Thank you,

Answer (score 3):

It's called Action Sheet. [Apple Document on Action Sheet](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/UIKitUICatalog/UIActionSheet.html)

Answer (score 2):

This view is called a [UIActionSheet](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOS/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIActionSheet_Class/Reference/Reference.html).